# getting a list out of a website /selenium /python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to grab a list from an element like

```html
<a href="/Max/Project" itemprop="name codeRepository">Project</a>
```

The xpath is

```
/html/body/div[4]/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h3/a
```

I already tried

```
ids = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("a[@id='user-repositories-list']")
```

but it does not display a list with the repositories of this git user.

BR and thanks

Comment: btw. it should be a list with all git repos listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the repositories' links of a git user like this:

```
repos = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='user-repositories-list']/ul/li/div/div/h3/a")))

repo_names = []
for repo in repos:
    href = repo.get_attribute("href")
    href = href.rsplit('/', 1)[1]
    repo_names.append(href)

print(repo_names)
```

Then, you just need to do some text parsing to extract the repo's names from the links.

Mind the nested structure of the html. Under id='user-repositories-list' one finds *all* the blocks for the repositories. `h3` stands for header of third order and the `a` tag signals a hyperlink.
WebDriverWait makes sure to wait until all elements are visible and can be found.